# Finding the minimum value cells orthogonally to a polyline

Tags: raster, r, line, focal-statistics

I have a raster (`rast`) and polyline (`poly`) as shown below with the corresponding data. For all the cells that line passes through, I want to find the minimum value among the cells that are located on the orthogonal of the polyline. I only want the minimum value and not the cell. But if I can also get the cell of the minimum value that's a bonus. Please see the image below for what I want

[image]

If the line is always vertical (or close to vertical) something like the following would work.

```
rast_f <- focal(rast, matrix(1, nrow = 1, ncol = 7), fun = min, na.rm = TRUE) #I am using ncol = 7 as I am only interested in up to three cells both ways. 

#now extracting 
#if I extract by line then the index won't follow the path so, creating points at every 1m throughout the length of the river
  nop  <-  round(gLength(poly))
  poly.p <-  spsample(poly, n = nop, type = "regular")
  
  #extracting by points and converting into a dataframe
  ext <- raster::extract(x=rast_f, y= coordinates(poly.p), cellnumbers=TRUE) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    magrittr::set_colnames(c("cell","ele")) %>%
    distinct()
```

However, the polyline is not unidirectional, so I have to adjust the weight matrix in `focal` every time it changes direction to get the minimum from the orthogonal cells.

Any suggestion to improve this method or is there a better alternative? The rasters I am working with are quite large so a faster method is preferable.

data

```
> dput(rast)
new("RasterLayer", file = new(".RasterFile", name = "", datanotation = "FLT4S", 
    byteorder = "little", nodatavalue = -3.4e+38, NAchanged = FALSE, 
    nbands = 1L, bandorder = "BIL", offset = 0L, toptobottom = TRUE, 
    blockrows = 16L, blockcols = 128L, driver = "", open = FALSE), 
    data = new(".SingleLayerData", values = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1208.45349121094, 1207.15441894531, 1207.19006347656, 
    1207.94274902344, 1207.89782714844, 1207.94274902344, 1209.11303710938, 
    1210.1640625, 1208.50305175781, 1209.26330566406, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.56213378906, 
    1207.99792480469, 1207.19848632812, 1207.94274902344, 1207.94274902344, 
    1208.01794433594, 1208.43347167969, 1208.52490234375, 1210.61877441406, 
    1209.56994628906, 1212.35241699219, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.55212402344, 1208.19763183594, 
    1207.61181640625, 1207.9072265625, 1208.43347167969, 1208.53259277344, 
    1208.56506347656, 1208.56506347656, 1209.91125488281, 1209.72192382812, 
    1217.07543945312, 1219.02136230469, 1219.72485351562, 1217.35620117188, 
    1214.68359375, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1208.24816894531, 1208.21142578125, 1207.71325683594, 1207.91076660156, 
    1208.19030761719, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53442382812, 1208.56506347656, 
    1211.30285644531, 1215.82885742188, 1214.61682128906, 1221.67639160156, 
    1220.3544921875, 1219.9892578125, 1217.69470214844, 1221.14685058594, 
    1219.81823730469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1208.55249023438, 1208.02697753906, 1208.017578125, 1207.400390625, 
    1208.65942382812, 1208.56506347656, 1208.53625488281, 1208.76940917969, 
    1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 
    1217.29479980469, 1222.43395996094, 1220.53955078125, 1222.69262695312, 
    1221.01965332031, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1208.05090332031, 1207.9970703125, 1207.96997070312, 1208.05041503906, 
    1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 1208.76940917969, 
    1208.76940917969, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 
    1222.4541015625, 1220.85107421875, 1221.82141113281, 1216.05773925781, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.44177246094, 
    1208.52172851562, 1208.26806640625, 1208.46484375, 1208.78295898438, 
    1207.81494140625, 1208.16723632812, 1208.69140625, 1209.5849609375, 
    1209.5849609375, 1209.5849609375, 1209.720703125, 1213.89770507812, 
    1214.76220703125, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1209.41796875, 1208.56091308594, 1208.10803222656, 
    1208.53002929688, 1208.42626953125, 1207.88256835938, 1208.81066894531, 
    1208.83459472656, 1209.5849609375, 1209.52807617188, 1209.81579589844, 
    1214.59741210938, 1223.80065917969, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.49841308594, 
    1209.14697265625, 1208.54370117188, 1208.89050292969, 1209.81579589844, 
    1209.81579589844, 1214.78759765625, 1221.84899902344, 1223.90710449219, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1208.6904296875, 1208.94995117188, 1209.23315429688, 
    1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1214.1171875, 1215.07580566406, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208.83178710938, 1208.76831054688, 1209.67565917969, 
    1209.67565917969, 1211.46594238281, 1214.94274902344, 1215.39904785156, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1209.25732421875, 1208.86218261719, 1209.048828125, 
    1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1211.82763671875, 1215.14599609375, 
    1215.67370605469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.06079101562, 1209.17163085938, 
    1208.79455566406, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 1213.59326171875, 
    1220.58471679688, 1217.48803710938, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1210.30834960938, 
    1209.05725097656, 1210.30346679688, 1209.67565917969, 1209.67565917969, 
    1215.83471679688, 1222.40283203125, 1218.2578125, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1209.61926269531, 1210.16052246094, 1210.56823730469, 
    1210.79309082031, 1210.46276855469, 1214.73291015625, 1216.96398925781, 
    1219.07653808594, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.46716308594, 1209.22875976562, 
    1210.47521972656, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1212.83312988281, 
    1216.43481445312, 1219.17358398438, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1210.00036621094, 
    1209.9521484375, 1209.96520996094, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 
    1213.79821777344, 1217.90661621094, 1219.22473144531, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1209.54418945312, 1210.26818847656, 1210.0283203125, 
    1210.03039550781, 1210.0283203125, 1212.66833496094, 1216.18420410156, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1209.45166015625, 1209.70434570312, 1209.33239746094, 
    1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1211.15905761719, 1212.17797851562, 
    1214.48999023438, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1209.94604492188, 1210.36206054688, 
    1210.103515625, 1210.0283203125, 1210.0283203125, 1211.44226074219, 
    1214.18041992188, NA, NA), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = TRUE, 
        fromdisk = FALSE, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), 
        haveminmax = TRUE, min = 1207.15441894531, max = 1223.90710449219, 
        band = 1L, unit = "", names = "nakkhu_hosp_10m"), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
        type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
        names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
    extent = new("Extent", xmin = 333003.9801, xmax = 333403.9801, 
        ymin = 3060402.4038, ymax = 3060602.4038), rotated = FALSE, 
    rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
    NULL), ncols = 40L, nrows = 20L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), 
    history = list(), z = list())
> dput(poly)
new("SpatialLinesDataFrame", data = structure(list(OBJECTID_1 = "2", 
    OBJECTID = "5", full_id = "w518744798", osm_id = "518744798", 
    osm_type = "way", boat = "no", name = "Nakhu River", waterway = "river", 
    alt_name = NA_character_, name_en = NA_character_, name_ne = NA_character_, 
    name_hi = NA_character_, layer = NA_character_, name_new = NA_character_, 
    tunnel = NA_character_, intermitte = NA_character_, width = "15", 
    covered = NA_character_, level = NA_character_, source_geo = NA_character_, 
    irrigation = NA_character_, source_nam = NA_character_, ford = NA_character_, 
    highway = NA_character_, descriptio = NA_character_, name_pl = NA_character_, 
    Shape_Leng = 0.03527734357, Shape_Le_1 = 0.03527734357), row.names = "1", class = "data.frame"), 
    lines = list(new("Lines", Lines = list(new("Line", coords = structure(c(333357.71109, 
    333347.93163242, 333322.09653121, 333300.04287981, 333280.09300607, 
    333258.02201581, 333214.4373047, 333174.21512831, 333140.61705414, 
    333112.04542794, 333090.49357056, 3060403.42043312, 3060416.94597164, 
    3060447.77469024, 3060469.39810868, 3060491.87924132, 3060530.9457756, 
    3060551.0690618, 3060554.46832418, 3060571.76216307, 3060586.46056643, 
    3060602.4038), .Dim = c(11L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
        c("x", "y"))))), ID = "1 1")), bbox = structure(c(333090.49357056, 
    3060403.42043312, 333357.71109, 3060602.4038), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
        projargs = "+proj=utm +zone=45 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
```

P.S: I asked this question on a different StackExchange site with no responses, I feel it's more relevant here, so I deleted the question there and re-posting it here.

Comment: When the line has a vertex in a cell then the line could have two directions within that cell. Which direction do you want? Its easy enough to find the cells a line passes through but how do you define the direction? And do you want orthogonal to the centre of the cell? Even if the line only clips the tiniest corner?

Comment: Good questions. 
First question - If I have to be too precise I will have to consider the angle that corresponds to the longest portion of the line. But for this particular problem, it doesn't have to be so accurate so any of the two angles would be fine. 
2nd question - Yeah, I need to consider any cell the line passes through regardless of how tiny the corner is. 
Thank you.

Comment: @Spacedman I am thinking of creating focal rasters of minimum values in different directions (45, 90, 135, 180) by adjusting focalWeight accordingly. Then pick the values for the points along the line from these focal rasters according to the angle of the line segments. I know it's not exactly orthogonal. But it would do the job for me. And I can't think of a faster method. Do you think there is a better or/and faster way? Thanks. Appreciate your comment on this.